# Laravel Access npm packages in .blade.php js

Tags: laravel, twilio-php

What is proper way to access npm package in js_section of blade.php file

resources\js\app.js

```
import Twilio from 'twilio-video';
window.Twilio = Twilio;
```

also tried with:

```
require('twilio-video');
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    CONTENT...
@endsection

@section('js_section')
    <script>
        const {connect} = require('twilio-video');

        connect('{{$result['token']}}', {name: 'test2'}).then(room => {
            console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
            room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
                console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participant}`);
            });
        }, error => {
            console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

**ERROR:** *Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require()` is not built in into the browser it is a node environment feature. So it has no access from a blade template. What can you do is to compile another js file in your `webpack.mix.js` and pass token into from a hidden input.

Write your code in **custom.js**

```
const {connect} = require('twilio-video');

// it will contain $result['token']
const roomToken = document.querySelector('.room-token').value;

connect(roomToken, {name: 'test2'}).then(room => {
  console.log(`Successfully joined a Room: ${room}`);
  room.on('participantConnected', participant => {
    console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participant}`);
  });
}, error => {
  console.error(`Unable to connect to Room: ${error.message}`);
});
```

Add it in **webpack.mix.js** and compile (with `npm run dev` for example - depends on your `package.json` scripts and environment)

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('path/to/custom.js', 'public/folder');
```

and in your **blade.php**

```
@section('js_section')
    <input type="hidden" class="room-token" value="{{ $result['token'] }}" />
    <script src="{{ asset( 'path/to/complied/custom.js' ) }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score -2):

Require and import are commands for Laravel-mix(webpack)

You have run Laravel-mix for build result from resource to bundles(prepared files).

Run in terminal

```
npm install
npm i twilio-video
npm run dev
```